# redis dump.rdb file not loading up

Tags: redis

I am using redis 2.6.9.  At the moment, I am not certain which version of redis the dump.rdb file came from (I am trying to copy over the redis info from another computer - I will look into the slave option if this does not work).  The dump.rdb file is in the parent redis directory.  In the redis.conf file, the names and directory locations appear to match with what I have.  I do not believe I have a file permissions issue.  However, when I start the redis server, it does not appear to read from the dump file and there are no keys etc in redis once the server is up.

**redis.conf**

```
dbfilename dump.rdb
dir ./
```

Any useful suggestions to troubleshoot/resolve the issue will be appreciated.  Thanks

** Update **
The rdb file I copied was in the wrong directory - I moved it to the src directory which resolved the issue (in retrospect, I could have changed the config file to point to an absolute pathname and that should have done the trick as well).

Comment: Are you sure you're loading the proper redis.conf file?

Comment: I have specified the redis.conf name as well when I launch the server - it does not seem to make any difference.

Comment: moved the rdb file to the src directory (previously using incorrect directory).  issue resolved (caused by pilot error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I placed the dump.rdb file in the src directory after which redis was able to load the data in the dump file upon restart.  The dump.rdb file location is specified in the config file and points to the current directory by default.